# How to check If the translation of a sql query to Django ORM is equivalent?

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I have these models:

```py
class Messages(models.Model):
    channel = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    publisher = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'messages'


class ReadMessages(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    message_id = models.ForeignKey(Messages, db_column='message_id', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'read_messages'
```

and I also have a legacy system who is using the same database, but this system is doing the following query in pure sql:

```sql
SELECT messages1.id, messages1.channel FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE channel IN ('U560'))
messages1 LEFT JOIN read_messages ON messages1.id = read_messages.message_id WHERE read_messages.id IS NULL;
```

I tried to do the same in Django ORM using the following code:

```py
Messages.objects.filter(channel__in=['U560'],readmessages__id__isnull=True).values('id', 'channel')
```

with the few tests i've done they returned the same result, but I still not sure if they are equivalents and if there will be a case where the two queries will return differents results.

Answer (score 2):

You can print the query with:

```
print(
    Messages.objects.filter(channel__in=['U560'], readmessages__id__isnull=True)
    .values('id', 'channel')
    .query
)
```

The query looks like:

```
SELECT messages.id, messages.channel
FROM messages
LEFT OUTER JOIN readmessages ON readmessages.message_id_id = messages.id
WHERE readmessages.id IS NONE
  AND messages.channel IN ('U560')
```

A shorter equivalent query is:

```
Messages.objects.filter(channel='U560', readmessages=None).values('id', 'channel')
```

and I would advise to drop the [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values): this returns dictionaries. Usually model objects are better suited since these contain extra logic like properties, methods, can access related objects, etc.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Message` instead of <s>`Messages`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `message`, instead of <s>`message_id`</s>.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the notes, they are named this way cuz I have used inspectdb from django because this is a db already in use, so django generated these names automatically

Comment: @LeonardoFurtado: yes, but if the name of the table is plural, it will of course also name the model plural. However you can rename the model, since the `db_table` is specified, and it will thus still query that database table.

Answer (score 0):

The two queries are equivalent and will return the same results.

The SQL query selects all messages with channel 'U560' that do not have a corresponding entry in the read_messages table. The Django ORM query uses a left outer join to achieve the same result.

In the Django ORM query, the filter() method filters the Messages objects with the specified channel and then applies a condition on the related ReadMessages objects. The readmessages__id__isnull=True condition checks if there is no related ReadMessages object, which is equivalent to the read_messages.id IS NULL condition in the SQL query.

Both queries will return a queryset of Messages objects with the id and channel fields that satisfy the specified conditions. As long as the data and database schema remain the same, the two queries will always return the same results.